# Genymotion doesn't show in AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device, genymotion

This is my first time with Genymotion (running on OS X 10.11)

I've already set path to sdk in Genymotion: "/Users/username/Library/Android/sdk" and install Genymotion plugin in Android Studio.

Genymotion icon shows up in Android studio and I can start Nexus 4 API 17 smoothly.

But the problem is... In AVD Manager, it has no Genymotion emulator.

How can I fix this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Genymotion is not an AVD, you manage it with its own plugin.
You should only care that adb does list it.

However I recommend you to take a look at the latest version of the emulators, they have become really fast.

Comment: Thanks for you fast reply!!
I fixed this!!!
I need to start Genymotion first then go to AVD Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Go to:
`android studio` | `Tools` | `Android` | `Enable ADB Integration`